# what and all setting we have to do to access local Database on my server

Tags: android, android-layout

I created and application which will sync data with local database on my server i achieve that my using jdbc codes . It is working fine on my Emulator. 
I made apk file of that and installed into my device. 
But How can i sync. I connected my device through USB and tried it but it's not syncing. I don't know what and all settings i have to make to connect to local database on my server.
I referred http://amitku.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database-server-from-android-app/ and http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ to do the coding..

Here is sample code which i'm using to connect to my database..
I'm using jtds.jdbc added jar file to access the local database.

```
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(
                            "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:dbname",
                            "username", "password");
            Log.w("Connection", "open");
            Statement stmtUserDetails = conn.createStatement();
            //Fetching Data From Tbl
            ResultSet resetUserDetails = stmtUserDetails
                    .executeQuery("select UserName,Password,Priviledges from TblmyTable");
```

I'm Getting The Following Error in Log-cat

```
11-02 13:19:05.249: D/SntpClient(73): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: What kind or error do you get? Show us the LogCat output and the relevant part of the code. Also note that using JDBC is not a good idea, it is very easy to read the connection string from the APK, including database user and password!

Comment: In my Emulator it's Working fine. while i'm trying that on actual device it's not working..what and all settings i have to change to make it work on my android device...

Comment: You didn't answer Márton. Please provide a stack trace and/or logcat snippet of the problem when using it on the device. Otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: @MártonMolnár I had edited the error which i'm getting on my LogCat..Please help me to solve this issue.