# Error While Trying to access local Database on my server Using Real Android Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I created and application which will sync data with local database on my server i achieve that my using jdbc codes . It is working fine on my Emulator.

Here is sample code which i'm using to connect to my database.. I'm using jtds.jdbc added jar file to access the local database.

```
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(
                            "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://195.169.100.1:1433/dbname",
                            "username", "password");
            Log.w("Connection", "open");
            Statement stmtUserDetails = conn.createStatement();
            //Fetching Data From Tbl
            ResultSet resetUserDetails = stmtUserDetails
                    .executeQuery("select UserName,Password,Priviledges from TblmyTable");
```

When i'm trying to Connect Using Device in debugging mode. I'm Getting the Following Error on My LogCat

```
11-02 13:19:05.249: D/SntpClient(73): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Please Help me to Solve this issue.

Comment: Unless your application is a time syncing application (which would likely not be connecting to a sql server), I believe the log entry you pasted has nothing to do with your application.

Comment: @mah Then what changes i have to make on device so that my application start syncing..

Comment: Aadi I have no idea, I'm merely noting that your pasted log entry appears unrelated -- but perhaps there is an actually related entry that will help if you look further? More information may help someone to help you, but only if it's valid.

Comment: what i also think is there is no chance of having bug in code. Because it's working fine on emulator. Problem is Occurring only while trying to connect using Real Device. I think there must be some settings we need to change in Device or in My Computer.

Comment: Now i'm Getting this error D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: this seems to be a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028357/what-and-all-setting-we-have-to-do-to-access-local-database-on-my-server.

Comment: Yah it is i didn't get proper solution that's y i posted it by updating..

Answer (score 0):

<strike>dbname does not seem to be a valid socket.</strike>

Try fixing the jdbc connect-string

```
    .getConnection( "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://195.169.100.1:1433/dbname",
                        "username", "password");
```

update

the database connect you gave me in the comment

```
 //192.165.100.3:1433/myTestDatabase", "aadi", "test123"
```

is not reachable from normal internet (i just tryed to open the database) and therefor not from the physical device. is there a firewall blocking the access?

Comment: Actualy it's Connection conn = DriverManager
     .getConnection(
       "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.165.100.3:1433/myTestDatabase",
       "aadi", "test123"); it's connecting to database on my server also using emulator getting problem only while trying to connect using device..

Comment: sorry, i cannot from distance. Maybe your local admin can help.

Comment: Okay...Now i can't give you update...I'll check tomorrow and let you know thanks for helping me...I'll inform you tomorrow..B'coz local admin is not available now.